# C# Distinct List from a List

Tags: c#, list, distinct

I have the **OccupancyResultList** list

```
 List<Occupancy> occupancyResultList = new List<Occupancy>();
```

of **Occupancy**

```
public partial class Occupancy
{
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> on_date { get; set; }
    public string type_code { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> available { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> rate { get; set; }
    public string rate_code { get; set; }
    public string publish_flag { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create another list that has the **distinct** values of **on_date,type_code,available**

**Distinct()** produces a distincted result of all columns which returns repeatitions.

Can you give me a hand plz?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ed38539f-fde4-4a2a-8e80-d058c32b332b/linq-select-distinct-c

Comment: If there are multiple Occupancy objects that have the same values for `on_date`, `type_code`, and `available`, which one do you want to show up in the results?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `GroupBy` with an anonymous type as a key:

```
occupancyResultList = occupancyResultList
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.on_date, x.type_code, x.available })
        .Select(g => g.First())
        .ToList();
```

Or [`DistinctBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) method:

```
occupancyResultList = occupancyResultList
        .DistinctBy(x => new { x.on_date, x.type_code, x.available })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I get the following error in your second hint: System.Collections.Generic.List<YApp.Occupancy>' does not contain a definition for 'DistinctBy' and no extension method 'DistinctBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<YApp.Occupancy>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you need to download MoreLINQ and add a reference

Comment: Selmann22 will this be OK as well? var newList = occupancyResultList.Select(s => new { on_date = s.on_date, type_code = s.type_code, available = s.available }).Distinct();

Comment: that won't give you a list of occupancies but a list of anonymous type with just three properties.